# How to read a specific value form a row in CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

I was trying to write a function that read a CSV file that looks like this.

flowers.csv

```
petunia,5.95
alyssum,3.95
begonia,5.95
sunflower,5.95
coelius,4.95
```

I have tried this code for my function.

```
def read_csv(csv_pricefile):
    import csv 
    f = open(csv_pricefile)
    li = []
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        li.append(row)
    f.close()
    print(li)

read_csv("flower.csv")
```

when I call my function it gives the following output.

```
[['petunia', '5.95'], ['alyssum', '3.95'], ['begonia', '5.95'], ['sunflower', '5.95'], ['coelius', '4.95']]
```

But I don't know how to write a function that will take two parameters for example,

```
read_csv("flowers.csv","alyssum")
```

If I call the function, it should give me the following output.

```
3.95
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free coding service, you should at least provide us with what you have tried.
What you can do is split the CSV by line, to make it an array. This array will contain as many key/value pairs as there are lines in your file. Then you can just select the desired key and get associated value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pandas library for read csv, this will make a dataframe object

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('flowers.csv')
df.columns =['flower','price']
```

Then if you want to know price of any flower

```
df = df.set_index(['flower'])
f = 'alyssum'
print("{} costs {}".format(f,df.loc[f].price))
```

Comment: thank you so much it was helpful can you just look at my solution if you don't mind just give me your thought.

Comment: I think that your proposed solution is valid, but what happen when your input data have more rows, for example flower color. Then you will build another dictionary? or create a dictionary where key is flower and the value is a vector with all data? In my opinion it's better use pandas library for read csv and create dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution I just tried

```
def read_csv(csv_pricefile,flower):
    import csv 
    f = open(csv_pricefile)
    my_dic = {}
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        myData = {row[0]:row[1]}
        my_dic.update(myData)
    f.close()
    print(my_dic[flower])

read_csv("flower.csv","alyssum")
```